# merge two json arrays, server side javascript, classic asp

Tags: json, asp-classic, vbscript, jscript

I have a classic asp (vbscript) page that I want to load and merge two json files on (apply one over the other recursively).

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
function MergeJson(dest, src) {
for (var prop in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    try {
        if ( src[prop].constructor==Object ) {
            dest[prop] = MergeJson(dest[prop], src[prop]); // recurse
        } else {
            dest[prop] = src[prop]; // update
        }
    } catch(e) {
        dest[prop] = src[prop]; // create
    }
        }
}
return dest;
}
</script>
```

The above function performs properly when I execute it client side (in Chrome, etc). But when I take the same function and add it server side, it fails. My calling code is in VBScript and is like this:

```
Sub GetJSON(byval path, byref oJSON)
    Dim str : str = GetFileString(Server.MapPath(path), "")
    If str = "" Then str = "{}" ' empty object
    Set oJSON = JSON.parse(join(array(str))) ' Douglas Crockford's json2.js
End Sub

Dim DefualtSettings : Call GetJSON("/defaults/settings.json", DefaultSettings)
Dim MySettings : Call GetJSON("/my/settings.json", MySettings)
Dim newSettings : newSettings = MergeJson(DefaultSettings, Settings)
response.write JSON.stringify(newSettings, null, 4) ' see it
```

I'm not that sure why it hasn't survived the transition to server side code. I've checked that I'm loading the json properly and that it  is able to be parsed as such (so it's valid), and executing essentially the same client side is working fine... I'm unsure how to debug the code server side, I don't have any development tools on that box, it's just a standard windows server with IIS 7.5.

Comment: Define "fails": Are there errors? Is the output not what you expected? How so? Also, is there supposed to be a difference between the `GetSettingsJSON` sub that's defined and the `GetJSON` function that's called, or is that a typo?

Comment: Also, you Dim a variable `DefualtSettings` (notice that "default" is misspelled), but in the second-to-last line, you refer to `DefaultSettings`. The standard advice is to always use [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of every script to catch typos like this.

Comment: Never mind the typos, I do typos all the time and they end up being how it is. I renamed the variables as I put them into SE since you'd otherwise tell me off for having totally undescriptive "a, b, and c" as variable and function names, which I also do while getting stuff working. Fails: means "when `DefaultSettings` has its values overwritten by `MySettings`, it returns a string [object object] to vbscript, but it does not do this when being called from javascript, you see `dest` as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBScript, if you want to assign an object reference to a variable, you have to use the [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement. Change this line:

```
Dim newSettings : newSettings = MergeJson(DefaultSettings, Settings)
```

to

```
Dim newSettings : Set newSettings = MergeJson(DefaultSettings, Settings)
```

Without `Set`, VBScript tries to coerce the right-hand side to a value type, usually by calling a default property, if it exists. In the case of the `MergeJson` function, it appears that the default property for JScript objects is the [`toString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xhc6yc%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function, which, by default, returns the string "[object *typename*]". This would explain why "[object Object]" is being assigned to `newSettings` when you don't use `Set`.

Comment: Cheers, remembering correct usage of "Set" always slips my mind when going back to vbscript.